# ORACLE SQL: Add data using nested conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't quite seem to figure out how to add data only where it exists.

I have a statement that I would like to add fields to. But rather than only pulling Employees if the criteria is met (ie the WHERE statement) I would like to associate the data if and only if it exists. My base statement pulls 30 records, but when I add more details to my WHERE statement (to include other fields), it drops the record count to 20. How do I retain my 30 records, while also including details from separate tables (if they exist)?

My base statement - it pulls 30 records

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_NUM "Employee #", 
START_DATE "Start Date",
NAME "Employee Name"
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN EMPLOYEE_DETAILS D ON D.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE D.START_DATE >= DATE '2016-12-14'
ORDER BY 1;
```

Output Ex.

```
    Employee # | Start Date | Employee Name
    1234         12/15/2017   Jim Doe
    1456         01/16/2017   John Dillin
    5435         04/23/2017   Jane Mitchel
    9876         09/12/2017   Joan Smith
    7655         10/14/2017   Barry Gibb 
   ...25 more records
```

Detailed Statement to include extra fields - it only pulls 20 records

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_NUM "Employee #", 
START_DATE "Start Date",
NAME "Employee Name",
OS.ONBOARDING_LOCATION "On-boarding Location",
OS.COMPLETION_DATE "Completion Date"
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN EMPLOYEE_DETAILS D ON D.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
JOIN ONBOARDING_STATUS OS ON OS.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE D.START_DATE >= DATE '2016-12-14'
AND OS.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'START'
AND OS.CANCELLED IS NULL
ORDER BY 1;
```

Output Example

```
    Employee # | Start Date | Employee Name | On-boarding Location | Completion Date
    1234         12/15/2017   Jim Doe           Sacramento, CA         12/13/2017
    1456         01/16/2017   John Dillin       Atlanta, GA            01/19/2017
    7655         10/14/2017   Barry Gibb        Los Angeles, CA        10/17/2017
   ...17 more records
```

Here is what I tried to do, but it only duplicated the records:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_NUM "Employee #", 
START_DATE "Start Date",
NAME "Employee Name",
(CASE 
   WHEN OS.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'START' AND OS.CANCELLED IS NULL
   THEN OS.ONBOARDING_LOCATION
   ELSE NULL
END)"On-boarding Location",
(CASE 
   WHEN OS.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'START' AND OS.CANCELLED IS NULL
   THEN OS.COMPLETION_DATE
   ELSE NULL
END)"Completion Date"
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN EMPLOYEE_DETAILS D ON D.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
JOIN ONBOARDING_STATUS OS ON OS.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE D.START_DATE >= DATE '2016-12-14'
ORDER BY 1;
```

My last attempt pulls the data, but doesn't seem adhere to the CASE WHEN statement and duplicates a lot of the records. Please let me know if that doesn't make sense. Any help or tips you can provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `left join` instead of `join`. This way when no related rows exist, you'll still get the main row (and null values in the related columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **OUTER** joins, as in:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_NUM "Employee #", 
    START_DATE "Start Date",
    NAME "Employee Name",
    OS.ONBOARDING_LOCATION "On-boarding Location",
    OS.COMPLETION_DATE "Completion Date"
  FROM EMPLOYEES E
  left JOIN EMPLOYEE_DETAILS D ON D.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
   and D.START_DATE >= DATE '2016-12-14'
  left JOIN ONBOARDING_STATUS OS ON OS.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
   AND OS.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'START'
   AND OS.CANCELLED IS NULL
  ORDER BY 1;
```

Please note I moved the filtering conditions (`WHERE` section) into the join clauses to enforce outer joins. If you keep the filters in the `WHERE` clause you are effectively converting back the joins into **inner** joins, and you don't want to do that.

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately it's still dropping records that don't have `OS.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'START'`. I can't quite seem to figure how to add data to the original data set, rather than further thinning the data set to meet the criteria.

Comment: Trying to understand what you want exactly. The query is retrieving all rows on `E` with (optional) accompannying rows on `OS`; but not all rows on `OS` are considered: only the ones with `START` in the description. Do you want something different?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm still trying to wrap my head around it myself. In my Base Statement above it returns 30 unique items. I'd like to add a column that shows, of these records, which ones have a start date. If they have a start date, display it. If not, leave it blank. Instead, what I'm getting in return is less records. It's dropping the records that don't meet the `OS.DESCRIPTION LIKE 'START'`. When I try a` LEFT JOIN` it seems to pull what I need, but it duplicates some of the records. And in those duplicated records the `Completion Date` is blank. There may be an issue with their data...

Comment: If you have multiple rows in `OS` for each row in `E`, then of course you'll get duplicate rows. What do you want in those cases? Randomly pick one `OS` row, the first one, the last one?

Comment: You're right. I was thinking about this backwards. Your original  solution was the right one. There was a secondary field forcing the record to be duplicated. When I added the new condition, it cut out the duplicated record (it wasn't actually duplicated, but since I didn't tell it NOT to pull those, it pulled them) while maintaining the original set. Thanks for working with me through this! I really appreciate it!